# highlight listview item oncreate

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to highlight a listview item in a master/detail flow on create. So when the activity loads up, I'd like say the second item to be highlighted already. How can I do this, code wise?

So far I've tried this:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(int id, String value) 
{
    if (mTwoPane) 
    {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt("num", id);
        ((ItemListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.item_list))
       .setActivatedPosition(2); //Setting it here
        arguments.putString("value", value);
        CountingFragment fragment = new CountingFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
    } 
    else 
    {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, CountingFragment.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra("num", id);
        detailIntent.putExtra("value", value);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
```

and it doesn't work :(

Comment: post your Adapter class, and in your adapter you can do something like , `if(position==1) view.setbackgroundColor(Color.red);`